# What is the best way to parse dynamic names in Json objects in Java?

Tags: java, json, dynamic, fasterxml

I would prefer to use com.fasterxml.jackson if that possible.
I'm looking for a way to parse json like this:

```
{
   "availability":{
      "48":{              //this is dynamic (in next response that number can be different, like 1023)
         "2018-02-08":{   //this is dynamic
            "temp":null
         },
         "2018-02-09":{   //this is dynamic
            "temp":null
         }
      },
      "49":{              //this is dynamic
         "2018-02-08":{   //this is dynamic
            "temp":null
         },
         "2018-02-09":{   //this is dynamic
            "temp":null
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Simply represent dynamic  data as Map

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: What do you have tried so far? What other parsers like snakeyaml?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GSON by google:

```
        import com.google.gson.Gson;
        import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
        import com.google.gson.JsonElement;

        HttpClient httpClient = httpClientIgnoreCertificates();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseEntity = null;
        try {
             response = httpClient.execute(get);
             responseEntity = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonArray jsonObjects = new Gson().fromJson(responseEntity, 
        JsonArray.class);
        JsonArray items =
   jsonObjects.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("availability").getAsJsonArray();
```

And than you can do actions with your jsonArray..

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do it in fasterxml Jackson.

1. Try using the JSON Tree model

The Api `JsonNode` takes care of converting the input String to a parsable Json Object. you can find the tutorials to use them in the following links [Baeldung's Site](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-to-jsonnode) , and API details are in [this link](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html)

I tried running your example here, PFB the debug screenshot...

[image: DebugScreenshot from IntelliJIDEA]

2. Try the Json Object Model as detailed in this [Dzone Link](https://dzone.com/articles/processing-json-with-jackson)

At the class level add annotation `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`
this will exclude any elements which are null when doing un-marshalling to the corresponding domain object

Comment: Sorry, but by dynamic, I mean that names will be for each call different so if I will make another call instead 49 can be 109

Comment: Hi Michal, I am assuming that your application will have a module/method which will return the key to be fetched. Example, whether the necessary key has to be 49 or 149. Either way, let us say that the key to be fetched is   String str. you can still do a findValue on the str.  Only solution of point 1 will be possible in this case..